# mailboxes not showing up after migration

Tags: linux, email, email-server, imap, dovecot

I'm migrating mail server over to a new machine running dovecot. Everything is running fine but I'm not able to see folders that users created on the old server. Messages that were in the inbox are visible however.

In my dovecot.conf, I have:

```
mail_location = mbox:/home/vmail/%d/%n/mail/:INBOX=/home/vmail/%d/%n/inbox
```

and I've checked the file permissions on both the inbox file and the mail/ folders; they are identical.

Is there another file that I need to change to tell dovecot to display these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that dovecot was returning bad results. Using the LIST-EXTENDED function sometimes has issues with dovecot 1.x. To fix it I forced LSUB command usage in my webmail configuration.